# c# How to save duplicates from list into dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I got list of Issues,
Where Issue

```
public class Issue
{
    public string version{ get; set; }
    public string someDescription { get; set; }
}
```

versions are duplicated e.g:

```
List<
     {"1.2.8", value1},
     {"1.3.1", value2},
     {"1.2.8", value3}
     >
```

and I need to split duplicates into dictionary, where key is a specific verison, and value is a list of values like:

```
Dictionary<stirng, List<string>> duplicates; 
what mean Dictionary<EachVersion, List<valuesForThisVersion>>
```

got something like this:

```
var VerisonList = records.GroupBy(r => r.Verison).Select(w=>w.Key).ToList();
```

this give me a list of versions, but have no idea how to fast get list of values where verison == VerisonList.element;

Is it possible with one linq?

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of the other question. In linked post there is no answer for my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using [`ToDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__):

```
records.GroupBy(r => r.Verison)
       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                     g => g.Select(i => i.someDescription).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's perfect!